# Unable to activate direct input mode on textfields

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, touchscreen, j2mepolish

I'm unable to activate [direct input mode](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/lush-ui/visual-guide/gui-item-textfield.html#textfield-DirectInputMode) on devices that don't support pointer events.

```
<variable name="polish.TextField.useDirectInput" value="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the project configuration to Generic/AnyPhone.